# Why doesn't the :not selector in CSS work without a specified element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet where the display of the paragraphs are determined by whether the container has the class `.dark-mode` or not.

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
:not(.dark-mode) .dark-mode-only {
  display: none;
}
.dark-mode .light-mode-only {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="light-mode-only">
    Only for light mode.
  </p>
  <p class="dark-mode-only">
    Only for dark mode.
  </p>
  <button onclick="toggleDarkMode()">Toggle dark mode</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, clicking the button adds the `.dark-mode` class to the container, but the `:not(.dark-mode) .dark-mode-only {...}` selector does not actually work. However, if I simply add `div` in-front of this statement, it works again:

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
div:not(.dark-mode) .dark-mode-only {
  display: none;
}
.dark-mode .light-mode-only {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="light-mode-only">
    Only for light mode.
  </p>
  <p class="dark-mode-only">
    Only for dark mode.
  </p>
  <button onclick="toggleDarkMode()">Toggle dark mode</button>
</div>
```

So what exactly is the issue here? Does the `:not` selector work only when the element is specified before it? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT** Even using something like `*:not(.dark-mode)` does not work.

Comment: Try `*:not( ... )` instead.

Comment: @MMD Does not work

Comment: Hmmm..... but here it said that it should work. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Comment: @MMD W3Schools has a lot of bad examples and code.

Comment: @JoãoHamerski I think you are missing the point of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:not(.dark-mode)` will match anything that isn't `.dark-mode`, including `<html>` and `<body>`.

So this

```
:not(.dark-mode) .dark-mode-only {
  display: none;
}
```

resolves to `body .dark-mode-only` and hides your text.

> #### Description
>
> There are several unusual effects and outcomes when using :not() that you should keep in mind when using it:
>
> - :not(.foo) will match anything that isn't .foo, including  and .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: So essentially there is no way to wildcard this type of negation?

Comment: I will do it the other way around, hide the text for darkmode until it's within a `darkmode` object. Actually, for the case of dark-mode, the media query `prefers-color-scheme` may be a better choice